# iOS Private API

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, iphone-privateapi

Our app, a splitview, requires that when portrait, show the master view automatically or through a custom button. I've been using a selector, `toggleMasterVisible:` and it works just fine. A friend told me it was probably private and now I am worried even though I scanned it with appscanner, validated it and read about it on a blog (Erianna).

What do you think?

Comment: It does appear to be an undocumented interface of UISplitViewController.

Comment: If you are using an undocumented method on a documented class then you are likely to be rejected for using a private api.

Comment: BTW - AppScanner is not an Apple tool. You can't rely on it in any way. Its website isn't available anymore either.

Comment: Oh, I mean, I validated it through xcodes organizer->validate. I thought it would let me know if I had any private apis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alternatives are (in level of difficulty):

1) Submit it to the store and see if Apple checks for it - if they reject it, it could cause a delay in acceptance that you might not want.

2) Replace UISplitViewController with one of the third party replacements.

3) Write your own controllers that do what you want them to do.